# How to bind data from request into existing object? Multiple steps form

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

in my method I have let's say UserDetails object which has some defined value like id, phone etc.
User changing only one value through form, it's email. Is the way how I could use method

```
userDetailsForm.bindFromRequest(new String[]{"email"}).get()
```

to not 'loose' previous values? The above example give me new userDetail object with only defined email field. Of course I know that I can use DynamicForm class, or just

```
userDetailsForm.bindFromRequest().get().getEmail()
```

but it would be helpfull to have method which does all this binding in one line.

=========EDIT

```
DynamicForm dynamicForm = Form.form().bindFromRequest(); 
String email = dynamicForm.get("email");
```

isn't that what I'm looking for.

**=========EDIT======================================**

In other words, I want to divide my form to 3 steps, but after every step I am doing update on DB. So for example when I am POSTing step2 I have object with values from previous step:

```
User [userId=8, createdById=12, name=null, active=false, country=EN]
```

so now when I am doing:

```
static Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class);
User user = User.find(8);
User user2 = (User) userForm.fill(user).bindFromRequest("name").get();
```

I am geting new object with empty fields:

```
User [userId=0, createdById=0, name="value from step 2", active=false, country=null]
```

I will be very greatfull for any advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I've figured out how to solve problem.
Here is discussion about this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/Form$20bind/play-framework/MtjBV5YNQ3E/QumAmLbMl5sJ
one of possible solution is here:
https://gist.github.com/nraychaudhuri/10590943

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
private static Form<Computer> editableForm(final Computer obj) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Form<Computer> form = Form.form(Computer.class);
            Map<String,String> data = mapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);
            Map<String, String> submittedData = form.bindFromRequest().data();
            data.putAll(submittedData);
            return form.bind(data);
        }
```

and my solution is below:

```
public T bind(T target, Map<String, String> newValues) {
    DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(target);
    binder.setAllowedFields(getAllowedFields());
    binder.bind(new MutablePropertyValues(newValues));
    return target;
}
```

=================EDIT

Here is important disscussion about security issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/Form$20bind/play-framework/uGrSlJMo48c/QnVjzP4ovqcJ

> `Form.bindFromRequest`
>
> without arguments. However, as probably most of you know, invoking
>   that method without parameters will bind all fields of the
>   corresponding model object to like-named request parameters, including
>   fields holding internal state that must never be set from the outside
>   (e.g. boolean isAuthenticated). That is, an attacker may set any field
>   and circumvent security if they only know the name of the
>   corresponding model object field. This is of course a catastrophic
>   security vulnerability (similar to PHP's notorious and deprecated
>   register_globals option:
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Form<UserDetail> submittedForm = form(UserDetail.class).bindFromRequest();
String emailID = submittedForm.data().get("email");
```

`data()` will hold name and value pair like following `Map<String, String>`, further retrieve value by providing its key name inside `get()` will return you the desired value.

Comment: your solution is the same like using DynamicForm.
`DynamicForm dynamicForm = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
String email = dynamicForm.get("email");`

Comment: @Adam If i am understanding your question correctly, you want to manipulate the email property in your controller upon receiving it from client submitted UserDetail object. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Calls methods like bind(), bindFromRequest() or fill() will return a new object filled with the new data. But I just need append date from request to my object. It's only matter of line of codes, cause I can do it by dynamicForm, by when I will have 50 fields it can be annoying.